# Make each column in a flex-direction:column flex-wrap:wrap list be no wider than it needs to be

Tags: css, flexbox

This fiddle largely works as intended, other than it seems to fill all the available width when it can:

https://jsfiddle.net/d16ba2re/2/

CSS:

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}

li {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}
```

`justify-content` doesn't seem to make any difference, no matter what I set it to.

Is there a simple trick to achieve what I'm looking for here, or am I out of luck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're looking for the [align-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-content) *property* with the *value* of your choice, here with the `flex-start`:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}

li {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>Six</li>
  <li>Seven</li>
  <li>Eight</li>
  <li>Nine</li>
  <li>Ten</li>
  <li>Eleven</li>
  <li>Twelve</li>
  <li>Thirteen</li>
  <li>Fourteen</li>
  <li>Fifteen</li>
  <li>Sixteen</li>
  <li>Seventeen</li>
  <li>Eighteen</li>
  <li>Nineteen</li>
  <li>Twenty</li>
  <li>Twenty one</li>
  <li>Twenty two</li>
  <li>Twenty three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Pure flexbox without any defined width or margin, not possible, https://jsfiddle.net/d16ba2re/13/ margin example, otherwise easy if combined with the grid.

Comment: Well the thing is that you cannot, with Flexbox, since it only takes the width of the widest column and "forgets" about the rest, this is due to the fact that flexbox is 1-dim. system, unlike the grid, which is the 2-dim. system. It is possible with some complicated JS, and much easier, if doing it with the grid.

Comment: Couldn't get my head around that.  Bear in mind that my list could be anything from one item to 100 items.  I'm sizing the UL via server side (`$height = (1.5 * ceil($list->rowCount() / $columns)) . 'em';`), and then sizing the containing box with the JS here: https://jsfiddle.net/d16ba2re/15/

Feels a bit hacky, but gets the job done

Comment: Yes, the grid is pretty broad and complex, takes some time to get the hang of it, but it's very powerful and useful "weapon" to carry nowadays and days to come. As long as it gets the job done, that's what's important. :)

Answer (score 1):

> I'll probably start a new question, but in case this is another dead-simple query for you... I also have problems when wrapping that  in a float:right . I'd expect the div to fully contain the ul, but the reality is that it bleeds out of it. jsfiddle.net/d16ba2re/3

Set a proper width to your div. I tried 295px and it seems alright.

Comment: Thanks, but the list is highly dynamic and will be different all the time.  I want a nice fluid solution that will grow/shrink as needed.  If I can't do it in CSS I'll have to use some JS, but I'd prefer to avoid that for obvious reasons.